# Sorting Parsed Data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a list of clients (which is a list of keys from the variable “clients"), with a simple `.sort()`.

I am unable to sort "clients", but I **am** able to sort "key_list" (they’re in alphabetical order in my console).

So...

What I'm seeing with document.write is a list of clients with "Client: (client_name)" with a line break after each client, which is good. But it's in no particular order.

What I'm seeing with console.log is an alphabetical list of clients, which is good. But there each client is not shown as "Client: (client_name)" and there is no line break. It's one large list, with each item separated by a comma.

Why am I unable to sort the keys in "clients"? Is it the way I'm trying to access the parsed "data"?

```
$.ajax ({

  url: 'data.php?',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

  var clients = JSON.parse(data);

  for (var key in clients) document.write('Client:' + ' ' + key + '<br>');

  var key_list = Object.keys(clients);

  console.log(key_list.sort(clients));

  }

});
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are getting.

Comment: You should learn about `console.log` and the developer tools

Comment: In the webpage I'm seeing...          "Client: WESTERVILLE, Client: AKRON, Client: TOLEDO, Client: BELLVIEW" ...etc.         In console I'm seeing...          ["ABBEYVILLE", "AKRON", "ADENA", "", "AKAMAI" ... etc}. The webpage has everything in random order, but in the right format. While the console has the right order, but I don't know how to get it in the right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because console.log() is only printing the key_list.sort(clients) object. So basically you are logging the object, not each element in the object.

So of course you are not getting the clients printed in the order you want in the document because you are doing that before you sort. Like Travis J said, you should use just .sort().

So you should do; `console.log(clients.sort());`

This will allow you to print the whole object and print out all the clients in sorted order.

EDIT:

```
$.ajax ({

  url: 'data.php?',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

  var clients = JSON.parse(data);
  var sortedClients = clients.sort();

  for (var key in sortedClients){
      document.write('Client:' + ' ' + key + '<br>');
      console.log('Client: ' + key);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a high enough reputation to "Up-Arrow" you!

Comment: No worries. console.log is a print function, it didn't have the format you wanted because didn't put it in there. Also, you didn't sort the clients before you printed them to the HTML, hence why they were random. Lastly, you can mark my answer as the correct answer. :) Please and thank you. lol

Comment: Can you write out the entire code?    For console.log(clients.sort()); I'm getting "sort is undefined".

Comment: @MatthewDuthie That's where it gets tricky. Can you show me the output of clients? So just do a console.log(clients);

Answer (score 0):

`sort` expects a callback function which takes two parameters, and also expects a return value based on a comparison between those two parameters.

```
.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; });
```

You are sending sort an object from deserialized json, which is not a function that takes two parameters and returns a value based on comparison, so the sort does not work. By default, sort will use a lexicographical comparison.

This would be the default call

```
console.log(key_list.sort());
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a high enough reputation to "Up-Arrow" you!